# Remove the space before line numbers which is used for breakpoints in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, gutter

[image: screenshot of what I am referring to]

My laptop has a small screen and I often use VS Code in half of the screen for multitasking, but I want more space in VS Code so that I can see more text on the screen, so I want to remove these spaces because I don't use breakpoints, and for me, it is a waste of space in the editor.

If is there any way to remove these spaces before lines?

Comment: This may not be possible @Ajay Sahu. Instead you can zoom out your font by pressing F1 then typing `Font Zoom Out` option.

Comment: you can inject CSS to customize the UI, use **Custom CSS** extension

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"editor.glyphMargin": false
```

The setting's description says:

> Controls whether the editor should render the vertical glyph margin. Glyph margin is mostly used for debugging.

This section of the UI is often called a "gutter" in IDE terminology. You might not belive it, but I found this tip as [part of the first result by googling "vscode gutter"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30795#issuecomment-353516966) (a comment in the GitHub issue: [Can the VSCode gutter be made smaller, i.e., decreased size/width? #30795](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/30795)).